# Как использовать стороннюю библиотеку в Crystal Reports?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, crystalreport

Я новичок в Visual Studio. В проекте документы формируются в Crystal Reports. Мне надо в документе создать штрих-код. Для этого я хочу использовать в Crystal Reports библиотеку для генерации штрих-кода. Как подключить это библиотеку (файл с расширением dll) к Crystal Reports? Возможно ли подключить библиотеку через NuGet мэнеджер? Код нужен gs1-128

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/438454/referencing-a-custom-assembly-from-crystal-report вот

Comment: эээ...это уже нашел, думал, может что-то новое придумали и не могу найти

Comment: Я бы сгенерировал текстом ШКИ используя символы ▌ ▐  █ . Думаю что писать плагин под майкрософт коробку, да ещё выдающий не текст, а изображение... долго нудно искать.

Comment: Используя шрифт Code 128? Я так сделал, но штрих-код получается неправильный - сканер штрих-код его не распознает

Comment: Я бы не завязывался на шрифт.

Comment: можно подробней? мне надо преобразовывать входные данные в штрих-код gs1-128

Comment: В 010 перевести можете (двочнопрерывистый код)? Если да - 00=' ' 01 = '▐' 10='▌' 11='█' всё. ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128, базируется на CODE128 Стандарт вот http://www.barcodeisland.com/code128.phtml

Comment: Почитайте https://www.barcoderesource.com/crystalreportsbarcode.shtml может и правда задать шрифт и вывести текст. Функцию засунуть в с# в обьект, обьекты сложить в `List<>` лист положить в датасет отчёта. Если не получается с "особым" шрифтом - переводитье в стандартные полосочки.